# Exception when trying to use Date in elasticsearch-dsl.py persistence api

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am trying to use persistence API, using elasticsearch-dsl version 6.2.1 as follow:

```
class MyClass(Document):
    start = Date(format='dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS')
    stop = Date(format='dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS')
```

When I call `MyClass.init()`
I see (through Kibana) that indeed the mapping is as I expected:

```
    "start": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"
    },
    "stop": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"
    }
```

I have variable `my_instance` which is an instance of `MyClass`.
`my_instance.start` and `my_instance.stop` hold strings like
'15-06-2018 02:54:05:382'

When I call `my_instance.save()` I get the following exception:

```
elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ValidationException: {'start': 
[ValidationException("Could not parse date from the value ('15-06-2018 
02:54:05:281')", ValueError('Unknown string format:', '15-06-2018 
02:54:05:281'))], 'stop': [ValidationException("Could not parse date from the 
value ('15-06-2018 02:54:05:382')", ValueError('Unknown string format:', '15- 
06-2018 02:54:05:382'))]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `elasticsearch-dsl` currently only supports dates in ISO format. If you want to use any other format you need to specify the (de) serialization yourself.

Comment: Thanks,
I replaced last colon with period i.e.  `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`  to make it work.

By specifying the (de) serialization you mean I should derive from `Date()` i.e. `class MyDate(Date)` and override `deserialize`?

Comment: exactly. You can also create completely custom field by extending `CustomField` (see examples in tests).